# Brother Printer Driver Prints Nonsense Upon Driver Installation?

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, printing, 18.04

I have a Brother printer (`MFC-7860DW`) connected to my WLAN. Every time I try to install the driver, it goes successfully. However, the test page is not the standard one and instead prints what seems like the code necessary to execute the instruction instead of the page itself. This is also the case when I try to print out any other page.

When installing the printer driver, I chose the SSDD option, and later tried manually specifying the IP address instead. They both lead to the same result.

Test Page:
[image: Test Page]

Comment: @Terrance In the `Add Printer` Section, my printer isn't listed. I also can't find a PPD file for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Download the tool:

```
http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz
```

The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory.
e.g. `/home/(LoginName)/Download`

Open a terminal window.

Go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step. By using the cd command.

Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

```
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz
```

Get superuser authorization with the `"sudo su"` command.

Run the tool:

```
bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1 MFC-7860DW
```

The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.

When you see the message `"Will you specify the DeviceURI ?"`,

```
Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI number.
```

The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete.

Comment: the directory is probably Downloads (rather than Download) so the command would be `cd Downloads` and for Ubuntu, surely `sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1 MFC-7860DW` is fine?